How to detect incoming VoLTE Video call on android?
I wanted to detect incoming video calls as I am working on auto-pickup calls, so currently my app auto-picked up video calls, so I do want to pick up video calls automatically. I have used the below code function for detection, but it does not detect video calls.
private boolean isVoLTEVideoCall(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
            if (telecomManager != null) {
                // Log all extras to debug video call detection
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
                        Object value = extras.get(key);
                        Log.d("IntentExtra", key + ": " + value);
                    }
                    // Attempt to get the video state
                    int videoState = extras.getInt(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_VIDEO_STATE, VideoProfile.STATE_AUDIO_ONLY);
                    // Check if the video state is not audio-only
                    return videoState != VideoProfile.STATE_AUDIO_ONLY;
                }
            }
        }
        return false; // Not a video call or older Android version
    }

